# Folder based retention policy

Tags: 2013, document-library, folder, information-policy

I have a SP2013 document library in which I need to set up different policies based on date to where a document would be deleted.  I found an OOTB solution but can only use that policy on one folder.  I would need to set one up for several folder because each folder would have a different criteria.  Anyone have recommendations including 3rd party software?

Comment: You could setup multiple libraries each with their own retention policy. Another, more complicated, option would be to launch a workflow instead of performing the delete and adding your logic there.

Comment: Having multiple libraries isn't an option I can use.  I did think of creating a workflow but can I was wondering, can the workflow run automatically to delete items each day or would I have to manually restart the workflow to delete items based on it's expiration date?

Comment: You can choose to launch a workflow instead of deletion as part of the library's retention policy. This allows the workflow to run based on an expiration date.

Comment: Another idea create content type for each folder and set the retention policy on CT. also check this one if it explain the things better. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2011/10/12/policy-and-retention-in-sharepoint-server-2010.aspx